# Is there a way to keep signed in status after redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I am working on a project that includes multiple pages(index and packages).
I am logging in on the index page using fire base and i have an  element that redirects me to another page(Packages)
It all works fine but when i get redirected i lose my login state.

I have the on Authentication state changed implemented in my JavaScript file and the two pages linked to it

I want the message to be kept when i move to the packages html page but it doesn't work
Any help would be much appreciated !

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
             // Add welcome msg
                }
```

Comment: Did you read the docs of firebase? Maybe this helps https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: Yes i did my problem is when i try to move from a page to another in the same website not on the same page

Comment: I don't lose my login state when I redirect, so you must be doing something different. Are you saying the `onAuthStateChanged` does not get executed on your new page? How did you test that? Can you create a page on something like jsbin/stackblitz/glitch that reproduces this problem?

Comment: No its not that i can still login from the new redirected page but the index page login state isnt persisted after the redirection

Comment: is there a chance that it has something to do with the redirection itself being based on an <a href="packages.html> ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist your login state (or any data) between multiple web pages, you need to use some kind of storage:

**Client Side Accessible Storage:**

- Cookies
- Web Storage (`localStorage` & `sessionStorage`)
- `IndexedDB`

**Server Side Accessible Storage:**

- Cookies
- `Sessions` (PHP)
- Database
- Server written files

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `Firebase`, but without knowing more, I'd be inclined to suggest `IndexedDB` because it's a) client-side and b) secure.